# Exponential distribution parameters

Tags: distribution, exponential, exponential-distribution

I need to set parameters in an exponential distribution. I know that every 5 seconds I can produce 4 object in average. What is the lambda value of exponential distribution?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about stats (try http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth This is not about stats. It's about knowing what the correct input to a stats-oriented program should be.

Comment: Perhaps; but it's still not a programming question.  In general, off-topic questions should be close-voted as such, so the OP can get more directed help in the correct place.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Why do you think determining correct inputs is not a programming question?

Comment: Because it has nothing to do with programming (in its current form), and everything to do with maths!

Comment: Excluding inputs and proper function parameterization seems to me a very narrow view of programming.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda is a rate, and rates are always quantity per time unit. Your lambda is `4/5 = 0.8` per second. Scale accordingly if your model is in milliseconds, minutes, hours, days, etc.

Potential pitfalls - The exponential distribution can also be parameterized by its mean, which is the inverse of the rate.  If the long-run average is 4 per 5 seconds, the mean amount of time between objects is `5/4 = 1.25` seconds. Make sure you know whether your software is using a rate or a mean parameterization. Also make sure that you're consistent on your time units throughout the program, i.e., don't mix seconds for one item with minutes or hours for other items.